# Need help using Selenium and Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to print each total price of every tv on this page. I tried this:

```
browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')

all_spans = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='item_total_price']")

for span in all_spans:
    print('span.text')
```

However, when I run the code, it doesn't print anything and it doesn't tell me which error occurred

Comment: It should be div and not span. There is no span tag there with class item_total_price.

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thanks a lot